# Gitlab and LDAP against CommuniGate Pro Server

Tags: ldap, authentication, gitlab

I'm currently trying to make our GitLab authenticate to LDAP that is provided by CommuniGate Pro server. When using command line tests (like `ldapsearch`) I'm successfully authenticating and getting information. But when I try to do it from GitLab's web interface I get

> Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials".

From the logs on the LDAP server I see the following:

```
11:39:51.061 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) BINDing as 'postmaster@mx01.ldap.net'
11:39:51.061 2 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) ACCOUNT(postmaster@mx01.ldap.net) connected(CLRTXT) [xx.xx.xx.99]:37160->[xx.xx.xx.251]:636(tls)
11:39:51.062 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) Logged in as <master>. authType=0
11:39:51.063 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) searching(base) ''
11:39:51.063 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) searching where (objectClass=*)
11:39:51.063 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) searching for (altServer namingContexts supportedCapabilities...)
11:39:51.064 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) '' retrieved
11:39:51.064 2 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) search finished
11:39:51.105 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) searching(sub) 'cn=domain.bg'
11:39:51.105 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) searching where (uid=f.lastname)
11:39:51.105 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) searching for ALL
11:39:51.105 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) search paging: n=126, cookie=''
11:39:51.105 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) 'uid=f.lastname,cn=domain.bg' retrieved
11:39:51.105 2 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) search finished
11:39:51.121 2 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) ACCOUNT(postmaster@mx01.ldap.net) disconnected ([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160)
11:39:51.121 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) BINDing as 'uid=f.lastname,cn=domain.bg'
11:39:51.121 1 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) BIND failed. Error Code=incorrect password or account name
11:39:51.122 3 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) request reading failed. Error Code=TLS connection closed by peer
11:39:51.122 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) TLS connection is closing
11:39:51.122 2 TLS-576189 closed by LDAP-000601
11:39:51.122 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) closing connection
11:39:51.122 4 LDAP-000601([xx.xx.xx.99]:37160) releasing stream
```

When I try with `ldapsearch`:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -H ldaps://mx01.ldap.net -D 'mail=f.lastname@domain.bg' -W -b 'cn=domain.bg' "(uid=f.lastname)"
```

I'm able to authenticate:

```
12:15:51.336 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) [xx.xx.xx.251]:636 <- [xx.xx.xx.33]:53142 incoming connection(mx01.ldap.net)
12:15:51.383 2 TLS-578274 created(TLSv1.2,AES256_SHA256) for LDAP-000612
12:15:51.441 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) TLS-578274(AES256_SHA256) connection accepted for DOMAIN(mx01.ldap.net)
12:15:51.448 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) BINDing as 'f.lastname@domain.bg'
12:15:51.448 2 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) ACCOUNT(f.lastname@domain.bg) connected(CLRTXT) [xx.xx.xx.33]:53142->[xx.xx.xx.251]:636(tls)
12:15:51.448 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) Logged in as uid=f.lastname,domain.bg=domain.bg,cn=domain.bg. authType=0
12:15:51.452 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) searching(sub) 'cn=domain.bg'
12:15:51.452 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) searching where (uid=f.lastname)
12:15:51.452 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) searching for ALL
12:15:51.453 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) 'uid=f.lastname,cn=domain.bg' retrieved
12:15:51.453 2 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) search finished
12:15:51.459 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) disconnecting
12:15:51.459 2 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) ACCOUNT(f.lastname@domain.bg) disconnected ([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142)
12:15:51.459 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) TLS connection is closing
12:15:51.459 2 TLS-578274 closed by LDAP-000612
12:15:51.459 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) closing connection
12:15:51.459 4 LDAP-000612([xx.xx.xx.33]:53142) releasing stream
```

My config is the following:

```
main:
  label: 'Domain.Bg LDAP'
  host: 'mx01.ldap.net'
  port: 636
  uid: 'uid'
  method: 'ssl'
  bind_dn: 'mail=postmaster@mx01.ldap.net'
  password: 'password'
  active_directory: false
  allow_username_or_email_login: true
  base: 'top'
  user_filter: ''
```

The `RAILS_ENV=production gitlab-rake -v --trace gitlab:ldap:check` check is successful too.

Anyone with similar issue? From what I see in the logs I think the problem is in `BINDing as 'uid=f.lastname,cn=domain.bg'` after authenticating with postmaster. Is there a way to make GitLab use `BINDing as 'f.lastname@domain.bg'` for users, after postmaster is authenticated instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For binding as `uid=f.lastname,cn=domain.bg` to work with CommuniGate that record should contain the `userPassword` attribute. The LDAP Central Directory in CommuniGate can be configured to copy account passwords to the directory records.

Another option is to enable the LDAP Direct Provisioning option in CommuniGate: it this case operations that use DNs pointing to account records will be run in the server account context, not in the context of LDAP directory record.